# Why "inscripserim" and not "inscripsi" in Haury's translation of "Le Petit Prince"?

Tags: contemporary-latin, conjugation

Haury's translation of the dedication of "Le Petit Prince" begins like this:

> Pueros oro ut mihi ignoscant quod librum hunc ad adultum hominem **inscripserim**.

I don't get why we have a subjunctive in the causal clause since in [Allen and Greenough's](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/causal-clauses) Latin Grammar, one can read:

> The Causal particles **quod and quia take the indicative, when the reason is given on the authority of the writer** or speaker; the subjunctive, when the reason is given on the authority of another.

I would have expected:

> Pueros oro ut mihi ignoscant quod librum hunc ad adultum hominem **inscripsi**.

Comment: I suspect this has a lot to do with the fact that *ignoscant* is already subjunctive: it would be very weird to have an indicative verb in a clause that is subordinate to one with a subjunctive verb, though I can't quite justify that intuition with a grammar reference. See Plautus, though: "...ut istuc insipienter factum sapienter feras, mihique **ignoscas** quod animi impos vini vitio **fecerim**."

Comment: Two examples from Cicero seem to bear this out: (1) indicatives: "quod non fecisti, ignosco"; (2) subjunctives: " id velim mihi ignoscas quod invita socru tua fecerim."

Comment: @brianpck: In Cicero's, "id velim mihi ignoscas quod invita socru tua fecerim" = "I would like you to forgive me this (id), because I did (this) to your unwilling mother-in-law.", why is "socru tua" in the ablative; not the dative, "socrui tuae", "I did this to..."?

Comment: @tony I read it as an ablative absolute. Assuming it has concessive force: "...that I did this though your mother-in-law was unwilling."

Comment: @Laravel: You might be interested in this answer from Vegwatcher: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18539/1982.

Answer (score 5):

This *quod* is best seen as a relative pronoun with implicit antecedent, or perhaps as a conjunction "that", not "because": "I beg children to forgive me for *the fact that* I have dedicated this book to an adult man".

I believe finite clauses dependent on indirect speech are often, but not necessarily, in the subjunctive: I think I once wrote a little paper about this, concluding, "it varies", I think by period, but even within the work of the same author. The conjunction *ut* can be said to introduce indirect speech here, and the *quod* clause depends upon it. So I am not too surprised to see the subjunctive.

Brian has given an example in the comments above that seems similar, with the subjunctive, by Plautus:

> obsecro te...ut...mihi...**ignoscas quod** animi impos vini vitio **fecerim.** — Plautus, *Truculentus* 4.3.54.

There is also this example from Cicero, with the indicative:

> velim mihi **ignoscas, quod** ad te **scribo** tam multa toties" — Cicero, Ad Atticum, VII.12.3.

Comment: I read that Plautus' Latin was a bit archaic and should not be taken as a model, but maybe I'm remembering wrong. Thanks for the references

Comment: @Cerberus: Is your paper available on the net?

Comment: @tony: Ah, no, I just wrote it at university in some Tacitus course, I think.